# Supervisor 3.3.1 running but not processing jobs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, supervisord

I have setup supervisor

```
[program:laravel_queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /usr/local/bin/run_queue.sh
startsecs = 0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/laraqueue.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/laraqueue.out.log
```

run_queue.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
php /var/www/html/application/artisan  --timeout=240 queue:work --tries=1
```

[image]

log file looks like this

[image]

but `job` table is filling up, its not processing any jobs. Any help in this regard is appreciated

Comment: Do the log files contain anything useful? Did you try manually running the laravel queue workers? Could you show us the `run_queue.sh` command?

Comment: @PtrTon i have updated my question, log file only contain `queue:work` command

Comment: added log file screenshot too

Comment: It seems like Supervisor is doing it's job well, so my best guess would be that there's something wrong with the job itself. Do the jobs process when you run `php /var/www/html/application/artisan  --timeout=240 queue:work --tries=1` manually? Did you try to see if the `handle()` method of your job gets called?

Comment: @PtrTon yup when i ran command manually it worked and i guess there was a slight change in command which i was running directly and one that was in `run_queue.sh` i changed it and it worked. You can post your answer and i will accept. I have posted a detailed description too for what worked for me.Thanks alot

Comment: Glad to help. You can accept your own answer as it contains all the details for other users to overcome similar issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some changes to make it work i am not really sure what actually made it work but here are steps:

I removed dependency on `run_queue.sh` and moved command inside `laravel_queue.conf`

```
[program:laravel_queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/application/artisan queue:work --tries=1
startsecs = 0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/laraqueue.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/laraqueue.out.log
```

also if you notice i changed command a little bit from

```
--timeout=240 queue:work --tries=1
```

to

```
queue:work --tries=1 (this made it work in my opinion)
```

after making these changes i ran following commands:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread & sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl start laravel_queue:*
```